# First radio transmitter. Taranis X-Lite, X9 Lite or Jumper T8GS?

Tags: first-person-view, transmitter, long-range-drone, control-input

I'm looking for a nice budget radio transmitter to start in the hooby and stay with it for some good time. I'm found these three good options but I'm tottaly newbie so I don't know the pros and cons of each one

I would like some radio that could make at lease abou 1-2 Km with no mods by default. And the most versatile about receivers.
I read the T8GS supports almost all protocols and it leads at this specification, but whay about the other ones?

I intend to some FPV

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this point I would recommend the radiomaster TX16S. It goes for about the same price as the other radios you list but has everything you need to get you going for a very long time.
FrSky (Taranis) is doing everything it can these days to lock you into their ecosystem and you need to start hacking once you are further in the hobby and want to switch over to crossfire for example.

With the TX16S you can use almost all receivers that are on the market.

Whatever radio you pick eventually, just make sure it runs openTX. Almost all instruction videos you will find online are based on openTX.

Comment: You made a good point about the Taranis that I didn't know it. And about the TX16S in which aspects it is better than T8GS Plus?